# SQL Query result with contains values from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, contains

I search a MySQL solution to collect queries, which contains some ints (ids in an array).

```
Example-Table:

id1 id2 id3
1   2   2
2   3   2
3   3   5
4   4   2
5   4   5
6   4   7
```

I have an array like

```
$id3array = (2,5);
```

I need id2 = 3 (not 4, because id2 "4" has one more id3 argument (7)

If I have an array like

```
$id3array = (2,5,6); // array can contains 20 and more arguments
```

In this example Table I need id2 = 0 (because no match)

My Tests with IN(2,5) or Group by was not successful - Is this possible to solve with MySQL?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71306/2

Comment: This is not clear. Please use enough sentences, phrases & words to say how the output you want looks as a function of input. Eg you write "because" but you don't clearly explain what the consequence *is* and you don't explain *how* the givens imply it. Also please read & act on [mcve]. Also fiddles are good but put relevant text in the question itself.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my bad english. I try to explain again: I need output id2=3 if my input is id3=2 and 5

Comment: Hi. Your English is not the problem. The problem is that you do not what you mean. You do say that a fragment of of the output is based a fragment of the input. But 1. you don't explain how, you just give numbers and 2) you don't say what the whole output looks like for the input in your example and 3) you don't say what it is an example *of*. You just hope we'll guess how arbitrary output is related to arbitrary input by looking at how one fragment is related to another. Please *explain yourself*. (Try using another language then translate.google.com which is lately way better via AI.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query. Put inner query which will match records which is not in desired array. Then group and count exact element

```
SELECT `id2` FROM `exampletable` WHERE `id3` IN (2,5) AND `id2` NOT IN (
  SELECT e.id2 from exampletable e WHERE e.id3 not in (2,5))  GROUP BY `id2` 
HAVING count(`id2`) = 2;
```

Here I have added **count(`id2`) = 2** because you have 2 elements in array

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71306/36)

Comment: thank you so much for your help! this is a excellent solution

Comment: for count(id2) I use in php count($id2array)